# Switched to a Bowden setup. Should I retract the filament out at the end of a print?

Tags: anet-a8, bowden

I switched my Anet A8 over to a Bowden and it's printing great. Moving that weight off has enabled me to almost double the speed and resonance problems have vanished.

My question is regarding after the print is done should I add a retraction code and back the filament out of the v6 or is it okay to leave it in there?

My concern is that if I leave it in there, will it cause a clog or anything when I warm up the printer tomorrow to print something else? If that's not a something I should be concerned about let me know.

Comment: That's not an issue, you can simply leave it in the hot end.
The only "end of print" clogs usually occur when leaving the hot end hot for a while - allowing the filament to drip out - and then retract the filament without feeding it against the nozzle once more. That creates a plug that's larger than the filament diameter that might get stuck in the bowden tube.

Comment: @towe That sounds like an answer and please do not forget to vote! Voting will help members get their [privileges](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) to e.g. vote and build this community.

Comment: That is definitely an answer and I appreciate your quick response.

Comment: Is there a way to mark this answered?

Comment: @Hellrazor - not without someone actually answering it. The above are all comments, which makes it conjecture. We don't want to steal towe's thunder, so are not wont to place it as an answer in their stead. Hopefully they'll come back on and place it as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

It's okay to leave the filament in the hot end, as long as you let it cool down with the hot end cooling fan running.

---

*From comment:*

> That's not an issue, you can simply leave it in the hot end. The only "end of print" clogs usually occur when leaving the hot end hot for a while - allowing the filament to drip out - and then retract the filament without feeding it against the nozzle once more. That creates a plug that's larger than the filament diameter that might get stuck in the bowden tube

Comment: You should put the details from your comment in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with towe's answer. I would leave it, retracting at most a mm or two just to avoid a mess. If you retract much at end of print, initial state for the second or later print is different from after just loading new filament, and this leads to different priming/skirt outcomes for the two cases, which can be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

After the completion of a print, remove the filament from the Bowden tube as it may break while not printing and can sometimes be difficult to remove. Basically if you aren’t going to do another print soon, remove the filament.